# With tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint, what are the valid string values for the 'monitor' argument?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Using the following link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint?version=stable
I am unable to determine the valid argument inputs for the `monitor` argument.
By default it is set as `'val_loss'`.

Where can I find the list of acceptable inputs for this argument?

With more context to my problem, I am trying to set a checkpoint that saves the "best" model following n numbers of epochs. But the "best" model is determined by the `monitor` argument - and the documentation on the page doesn't seem to display the "acceptable" inputs. I'd like to save the "best" model based on the most balanced precision/recall (F1-score).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `monitor` arg of `ModelCheckpoint` expects you to provide a string, this needs to be the name of a metric or a loss, for example, if your compile method looks like this

`model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['mae', 'accuracy'])`

the valid strings for `monitor` arg would be:

`'train_loss'`, `'val_loss'`, `'train_mae'`, `'val_mae'`, `'train_accuracy'`, `'val_accuracy'`.